# How do I implement "enable" or "disable feature" similar to Drupal Gardens?

Tags: 7

I'm interested in implementing something similar to the way Drupal gardens let you enable and disable features in the create-site interface. (I mean the term features figuratively, not necessarily the features module.) Is this just some sort of custom form that hooks into enabling and disabling modules?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's a nicely themed and stripped-of-options version off the modules page, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see on that page is a Drupal form where the form fields have been heavily themed to appear differently from how you would normally see that type of form field on a Drupal site.

Looking at the HTML source of that page, it is clear those selectors are simply checkboxes rendered with a custom theme function.

```
<div class="form-item" id="edit-features-28711-wrapper">
 <label class="option" for="edit-features-28711"><span class="feature-icon" style="background: url(/sites/default/files/connect.png) no-repeat center center;">&nbsp;</span><input type="checkbox" name="features[28711]" id="edit-features-28711" value="1"   class="gardens-feature-checkbox" /><span class="label-text">Follow us</span></label><div class="feature-preview"><img class="preview-image" src="/sites/default/files/stay-connected_0.png" />Gain a following. Provide links to your (or your users') profile on Twitter, Facebook or other social networks.</div>
</div>
```

There is also custom JavaScript code that changes the appearance of the form field.

When I turn off a feature, I see a CSS class being added to a tag, and another tag value being changed. The value associated with the checkbox is not changed; it is 1 when the feature is enabled, and it is still 1 when the feature is disabled.

[image: screenshot]